# Does a silverlight and xna application count as a game?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm making a simple game using the "Windows Phone Silverlight and XNA Application" type of project.

But I wonder, does it count as an application or game? Or is this something that I define when I upload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Silverlight, XNA, or XNA + silverlight project can be a game. You just have to make sure that while submitting it to the marketplace you choose the games as category.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that's something that you define when you upload the app. But that's really just a category selection. Games are in fact apps too, but are more oriented towards... playing, unlike productivity apps for example.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [Application Submission FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202922%28VS.92%29.aspx) it can be a game, it depends on your content. You have to know what your game does.. a notepad (joke) is not a game. So if its a game and you can categories in one of the game categories you can for sure submit it as a game as it should be.